# Delete last line of file, when using the data to draw a chart c#

Tags: c#, file, charts, line

I am in a trouble, when I am trying to delete the last line of my csv file, when I'm trying to draw a chart of the data.
My file contains a lot of data, which I get through the following code:

```
public void StreamOpen()
    {
        Stream stream;

        OpenFileDialog getDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        getDialog.Filter = "csv File|*.csv";
        getDialog.Title = "Get a .csv file";
        if (getDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((stream = getDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                strFileName = getDialog.FileName;
                string[] filetext = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName);
            }
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public void OpenFile()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(strFileName))
        {
            ListA();
            ListB();
        }
        if (strFileName != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(strFileName));
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');
                UpdateChart();

                listA.Add(values[0]);
                listB.Add(values[1]);
            }
        }

            ListA();
            ListB();
    }
```

The problem is, that in the last line of my file, I save a text like

> "Count of movements" + value

, and this value I want to skip when drawing that chart, instead I want to show that value in a textbox.
Now a error occur, that listA and listB is not the same, and I see why, because that last line is taken as a part of listA.

Hope you can help me to delete that last line, and help me to show how to save that value in a textbox.

Output in textfile:

```
09:03:28 ; 0 
09:03:29 ; 1 
09:03:30 ; 0 
09:03:31 ; 0 
Count of movements 2
```

Comment: Please show some "typical last three lines" of your CSV file

Comment: 09:03:26 ; 0

09:03:27 ; 0

09:03:28 ; 0

09:03:29 ; 1

09:03:30 ; 0

09:03:31 ; 0

Count of movements 2

Comment: Please add the file contents **formatted** to your question. No formatting in comments...

Comment: Now you see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line.StartsWith("Count")) 
              break;
            /....
        }
```

Skip if last line starts with certain string

Comment: int count = File.ReadLines(strFileName).Count();

Comment: This reads the files twice. Also a problem (performance) if files get large

Comment: Can you help me, to save that number value in a textbox.
I've tried, but it doesn't get shown.
MY guess was:

NumTB.Text = line.PadLeft(16);

Comment: NumTB.Text = line.Substring("Count of movements".Length);

Comment: It doesn't work for me.
Still the textbook is empty.

Comment: if (line.StartsWith("Count"))
                {
                    string s = line.Substring("Count of movements".Length);
                    break;
                }
This worked for me and I get the number.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

```
string[] values = line.Split(';');
if(values.Length != expected_column_count) // then ignore
```

---

**Edit**

Or if something other is *special* about the unwanted line, for example it always starts with the same text:

```
if(line.StartsWith(unwanted_prefix)) // then ignore
```

Comment: But the fact is, that I don't know the column count, because it will vary from time to time.

Comment: So you need to find something that is special about your last line. foe example: Does its start with the same text always? Then use this characteristics to ignore that line while reading the file.

Comment: Yes, it always starts with the same text.